# regular expression to replace div

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace, html-lists

i need regex in c# way to replace following tags:

`<div class="tr-summaryinfo">'
<p class="tr-summaryitem">test </>
</div>`

it should look like

`<ul class="tr-summaryinfo">'
<li class="tr-summaryitem">test </li>
</ul>`

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I need stuff too

Comment: StoryResult = Regex.Replace(StoryResult, "<div class=\"tr-summaryinfo\">(.|\n)*?</div>", "<ul>$1</ul>");

i tried this way.

Comment: this is replacing content as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses 2 Replace calls which might be OK if the code is not executed too frequently:

```
string input =
@"<div class=""tr-summaryinfo"">'
<p class=""tr-summaryitem"">test </>
</div>";

string result = Regex.Replace(input, 
     "<div class=\"tr-summaryinfo\">(.*?)</div>", 
     "<ul class=\"tr-summaryinfo\">$1</ul>",
    RegexOptions.Singleline);

result = Regex.Replace(result, 
     "<p class=\"tr-summaryitem\">(.*?)</p>", 
     "<li class=\"tr-summaryitem\">$1</li>",
    RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Note that you need ? in the patterns to avoid the greedy behavior

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N6jMks)

Comment: thank you, but it should not replace all the divs, only which has those classnames

Comment: Do div and p always have a single class attribute? If not it'd probably be easier to use an HTML parser like HTML agility pack.

Comment: yes, these classnames are fixed for both div and p tags.

Comment: And class is the only attribute specified, right?

Comment: yes, there are no other attributes apart from class

Comment: @sukeshchukki I updated the code with a different approach

Comment: awsome. it worked. thank you @vc 74

Comment: Make sure you mark this answer correct if it suits your purpose

Comment: @vc74 can you please have a look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815333/retain-html-tags-after-xslt

Comment: @sukeshchukki Seems you found a solution for that one too

Comment: @vc74 yes, thank you for looking into.