# retain HTML tags after xslt

Tags: html, xml, parsing, xslt

i have following xslt parsing tree.

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='tr-summaryinfo']"> 
    <ul>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ul>
  </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="p[@class='tr-summaryitem']">
   <li>
 <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </li>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="body">
   <div id="storybodycontent">
      <span class="storycontent">
       <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
     </span>
   </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

input is:

```
<html test="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>US STOCKS-PepsiCo, oil help extend Wall St rally; S&amp;P at 4-month high</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tr-summaryinfo">
<p class="tr-summaryitem">Energy shares jump as oil gains on supply disruptions </p>
<p class="tr-summaryitem">PepsiCo's best day in 7 yrs on strong Q2</p>
<p class="tr-summaryitem">Nordstrom down on disappointing forecast</p>
<p class="tr-summaryitem">S&amp;P 500 Q2 earnings growth seen at 21 pct -TR I/B/E/S</p>
<p class="tr-summaryitem">Tesla gains on plans to open new plant in Shanghai</p>
<p class="tr-summaryitem">Indexes up: Dow 0.56 pct, S&amp;P 0.30 pct, Nasdaq 0.14 pct</p>
</div>
<p class="tr-advisory">Changes comment, adds details, updates prices</p><p class="tr-by">By Amy Caren Daniel</p><p class="tr-story-p1"><span class="tr-dateline">July 10 (Reuters)</span><span class="tr-dl-sep"> - </span>
```

i want to retain some tags as it is after parsing. BUt my current parsing returns plain text.

`<div class="tr-summaryinfo">` and `<p class="tr-summaryitem">` being converted as expected, rest of the content looses its tags returned as plain text.

`<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` returns all tags as they are, but vomits transformation.

please help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to retain some tags as is in the output, you can start with an `identity transform template` which copies the input as is to the output.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In the template matching `body` use `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead of `<xsl:copy-of>`.

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <div id="storybodycontent">
        <span class="storycontent">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </span>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The complete XSLT will look like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <div id="storybodycontent">
            <span class="storycontent">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </span>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='tr-summaryinfo']">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class='tr-summaryitem']">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should give the required output.